# Vector Fields as a section of the Tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

In most textbooks for differential geometry a vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ is said to be a section of the corresponding tangent bundle $TM$. I give the definition I am provided with and then explain my confusion about this definition: 
A smooth vector field on $M$ is a smooth map
\begin{align}
X:M\rightarrow TM
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\pi\circ X = id_M\end{align}
where $\pi:TM\ni (p,v_p)\rightarrow p\in M$ is the tangent bundle projection. 
In my lecture notes it says, that the last definition ensures that $X(p) \in T_pM$. This is where my confusion starts. Is $X(p)$ now an element of the tangent bundle $TM$ as in the definition above or is it an element of the tangent space $T_pM$? Shouldn't one cosider the map $v:M \rightarrow T_pM$ defined in
\begin{align}
X: M\ni p \rightarrow (p,v(p)) \in TM
\end{align}
as the vector field instead of $X$?

Comment: Maybe your confusion comes from thinking of $T_pM$ as a separetely defined entity indepedent of the tangent bundle $TM$. Here one should think of $T_pM$ just as a subset of $TM$, defined as the preimage under $\pi$ of the point $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, a vector field associates, with each point $p$ on the manifold, a vector in $T_pM$. And we would like to phrase this association as a function. Then we have the challenge: What is the codomain of this function? Clearly it can't be just $T_pM$, because what about the vector field values at points other than $p$?

You say $v:M\to T_pM$, but this runs into exactly this problem. Where does $v(q)$ live, for $q\neq p$? We would like it to live in $T_qM$, but by our definition it lives in $T_pM$, which is a completely different space.

The most sensible codomain for the entire vector field is the full tangent bundle $TM$. As a set, the tangent bundle is the union of all the different tangent spaces $T_pM$ at all possible points $p\in M$, so it's in a natural way the smallest possible codomain we could hope for. Then, of course, since we want the vector field's value at $p$ actually does lie in $T_pM$ (rather than some other $T_qM$), we have to add the extra stipulation that $\pi\circ X = id_M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which helps me to clarify my confusion. I'd like to add the observation, that the elements in $TM$ do NOT have the structure $(p,v_p)$. This can only be the case if the tangent bundle is trivial. As in the comment above one should think of the tangent space as a subset of the tangent bundle $T_pM \subset TM$.

Comment: @Aralian Yes, of course. Not every tangent bundle is trivial. Locally it does have that form, but there is often no way to reconcile it across the entire manifold (at least in a continuous manner).

Answer (score 1):

One often thinks of the tangent space $T_p M$ as subset of the tangent bundle $TM$ and in this sense you can understand the statement $X(p)\in T_pM$.

I believe that part of your confusion stems from the notation $(p,v)$ for elements in $TM$. As a set $TM$ can be viewed as a disjoint union of all tangent spaces $TM = \coprod_{p\in M} T_p M$ and the projection $\pi\colon TM\to M$ simply tells you in which tangent space an element of $TM$ lives. For this reason some people denote elements in $TM$ simply by $v$, keeping in mind that $v\in T_p M$, where $p:=\pi(v)$. In this sense it is redundant to include $p$ in the notation for elements of $TM$. Another group of people likes to include $p$ in the notation anyways (say, to avoid always having to define $p:=\pi(v)$) and instead of $v$ they prefer the notation
$
 (p,v)
$
for elements in $TM$. Writing this as a tuple is merely a notational device and you should keep in mind that $TM$ is not (in any natural way) a Cartesian product of two sets.